# How to use Apoc font family in latex?

Tags: fonts

I need to use the following font in my latex editor:

https://blazetype.eu/typecatalogue/apocalypse

Does anyone know the name of the package or the script to use the Apoc font family in my latex editor?

I am using https://www.texstudio.org/ as latex editor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For this, it is not important which editor you use. But you should take a look at the `fontspec` package. You can load any font that you also would be able to install on your operating system with this package, but you would need to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

This example will get you started.

1. Download a trial sample of the Apoc typeface `Apoc-Trial-OTFTTF.zip`
2. Create a subdirectory `APOC` in the directory you are going to compile `Test_Apoc.tex`
3. Put in that subdirectory the `.otf` files received.
4. Load `Test_Apoc.tex` in TeXstudio. (Any other LaTeX editor will do).
5. If using TeXstudio compile the file with `Buid & View` or `F5`.

[image: a]

[image: b]

This is the file `Test_Apoc.tex`. Must use `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

```
%% File Test_Apoc.tex

% !TeX TS-program =xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    
\newfontfamily\apocfamily[%
Path =./APOC/,%
Extension = .otf,%
UprightFont=*-Regular,%
BoldFont = *-Bold,%
ItalicFont=*-RevelationsItalic,%
BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]{ApocLCTrial}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
The Apoc(alypse) Huge normal font \\\bigskip
{\apocfamily\Huge As I walked through the deep dark woods, we sang. }
\end{center}

\begin{center}
The Apoc(alypse) Huge italic font \\\bigskip
{\apocfamily\itshape\Huge As I walked through the deep dark woods, we sang. }
\end{center}

\begin{center}
The Apoc(alypse) Large normal font \\\bigskip
{\apocfamily\Large As I walked through the deep dark woods, we sang. } % \punct{}\dashes\\ }
\end{center}

\begin{center}
The Apoc(alypse) Large italic font \\\bigskip
{\apocfamily \itshape\Large As I walked through the deep dark woods, we sang. } % \punct{}\dashes\\ }
\end{center}

\begin{center}
The font Apoc(alypse) in its normal size \\ \bigskip
{\apocfamily    As I walked through the deep dark woods, we sang.} \\\bigskip
and the Computer Modern Roman for comparison \\
 As I walked through the deep dark woods, we sang.
\end{center}

\bigskip    
    
 End of the test file.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Simon Dispa , further to this question: How can I use the aacute characters in the latex? I tried \acute{a} or \'{a} with no success. Would appreciate if you update the script above with acute characters support?

Comment: @user56379 To get aacute characters you need the full font. Use a free font or buy the Apoc. The trial version has a limited number of characters.